# Meanings of these(java)

Tags: java

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{   
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 480);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawRect(60, 200, 100, 250);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString("My name is James", 200, 400);    
}
```

I want to know the exact meanings of these java attributes.And please tell me this too

**can i change the "g"(can i call it any name)**

**How this setColor works? and much more about what you know?**

Comment: all questions answered here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/package-summary.html

Comment: Read the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html) first then come back with a valid question

Comment: I'm amazed how lost people can be even with Google's warm and helping hands around all of us, not having to look up books that might or might not contain the relevant answers, for the right version of programming language used... It seems, times don't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void paint(Graphics g)  
/*
Above The name of the method, methods are ways (re-usable blocks of code) of operating on objects
public means the method can be called from outside or inside it's package
void means that the method does not return a value, 
for example if void was changed to int, then this method would give out an int value when run
the 'g' is a variable of type Graphics which is local to this method. The g can be changed to    
any legal variable name and it will only affect the code within the method as that is where it is used.  
So if you changed g to helloMyNameIsEarl for example, all the places where g is referenced
in the code below would error, until you swapped wherever g is referenced to helloMyNameIsEarl
eg helloMyNameIsEarl.setColor(Color.WHITE);

*/
{   
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 480);
g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
g.drawRect(60, 200, 100, 250);
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawString("My name is James", 200, 400);    

/*
All of the above g.something(something, something) are methods being called on g, which is     referencing the 
Graphics object passed to it (Look up pass by value in java methods) so your method you have is     receiving a 
Graphics object and performing the operations between the { } on it.
*/
}
```

The below link will give you more info.  This is the Java Standard edition API and gives details
on methods like the ones above.
Java Se 7 api [Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html)  This will detail the method and it's 'attributes' in more detail.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanx dr...I get a better understanding about methods and many more..again thanxx